# Save the Excel Webpart changes in SharePoint Online

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

I have been displaying an Excel Workbook as a webpart in SharePoint Online. The users are allowed to edit the excel file. I am trying to save the changes done by the user.

Is there any other way to save the changes in workbook other than [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office2010developertrainingcourse_solutiondevelopmentexcelserviceslab_topic4)?

I have posted this question over in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10487944/578738) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Editing an Excel document similar to Skydrive and displaying the results in an Excel Services Web Part is possible with an O365 E3 or E4 plan (it is not possible with only a SharePoint online subscription).

In order to edit an Excel document in the browser you need to have Office Web Apps (edit ability, not just the read only ability included in E1) which is only included in the Office 365 P1, E2, E3 and E4 plans. If you only own SharePoint online (and not the entire suite) Office Web Apps are not included with the license and it must be purchased separately.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think we have E3 and I am able to edit the excel in the web part. But I am looking for solution to save the changes done in the webpart other than using ECMA script.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it the changes are automatically saved in SharePoint Online. Or are you referring to they add a value to the Excel Services Web Part and that isnt saved. The web parts are more for analysis and reporting and  not for actuall modification like if you were to edit the document through the browser.

Comment: I am trying to have Excel to allowed to edit similar to Skydrive in the browser and generate reports after modification. Do you think I am taking wrong approach?